# how does serialized objects work within powershell

Tags: powershell, serialization

as amateur the question about serialization.

```
Get-Mailbox | Where-Object {$_.userprincipalname -like "*@network.local"}  |   Set-Mailbox -UserPrincipalName $_.name+'@newco.com'
```

Why does powershell complains with:

> Cannot bind parameter 'UserPrincipalName' to the target. Exception setting "UserPrincipalName": "The property can't be empty."
>   At C:\Users\adminmt\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp_11wcqppu.sax\tmp_11wcqppu.sax.psm1:51581 char:9
>   +         $steppablePipeline.End()
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.SetMailbox

see that 
TypeName: Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.Mailbox

What do I not untherstand about serialized objects :)

Thanks.

of course there will be other options to accomplish this, but the intention is to understand the mechanism.

that the name attribute is been used to modify the UPN

Comment: Do you run this command remote?

Comment: You'll have to put `$_.name+'@newco.com'` into a scriptblock {}

Comment: Yes Olaf, I do this remote. If putting like you say then it makes the UPN name literally $_.name+ @newco.com As an amateur I see that the used syntax works with normal object (not serialized) but way not here?  Sorry for not understanding.

Comment: $t= get-mailbox aboekel
$t | ? {$_.userprincipalname -like "*network.local"} | % { Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.Identity -UserPrincipalName ("{0}@transdev.nl" -f $_.name) }

Comment: This works: $t= get-mailbox aboekel
$t | ? {$_.userprincipalname -like "*network.local"} | % { Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.Identity -UserPrincipalName ("{0}@transdev.nl" -f $_.name) }    What doesnt work is:  get-mailbox aboekel | ? {$_.userprincipalname -like "*network.local"} | % { Set-Mailbox -Identity $_.Identity -UserPrincipalName ("{0}@transdev.nl" -f $_.name) } So what is technically the difference? Why is the pipeline handle a variable with mailbox object different compared with the output of get-mailbox command?

Comment: According Microsoft I should get a mailbox object . But I get a PS object back....help :( Im lost 0053) § {~} (Get-Mailbox TestuserX).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                  
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                  
True     True     PSObject                                 System.Object

Comment: Now see that I asked a question two years ago, you asked for additional information, to which I did not respond. Sorry, have to log in more often.